# Loading nested JSON data into Gantt Chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I am currently in the process of <strike>upgrading</strike> migrating my amCharts from V3 to V4 (I wish I hadn't started!) - One of the many issues I'm facing is trying to create a Gantt chart with JSON data.

I had no issue doing this using V3 library, but for the life of me I can't wrap my head around version 4 configuration.

This is how I loaded data using V3 (without any issues):

```js
var chart_today = new Date();
var chart_month = chart_today.getMonth() + 1;
var chart_day = chart_today.getDate();
if (chart_month < 10) chart_month = '0' + chart_month;
if (chart_day < 10) chart_day = '0' + chart_day;

$('.ganttdiv').each(function(obj) {
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart(obj, {
    "type": "gantt",
    "theme": "light",
    "responsive": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "marginRight": 70,
    "period": "mm",
    "precision": -1,
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "columnWidth": 0.5,
    "valueAxis": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "graph": {
      "fillAlphas": 1
    },
    "rotate": true,
    "categoryField": "category",
    "segmentsField": "segments",
    "colorField": "color",
    "startDate": chart_today.getFullYear() + "-" + chart_month + "-" + chart_day,
    "startField": "start",
    "endField": "end",
    "durationField": "duration",
    "dataLoader": {
      "url": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/zkhs3",
      "async": true,
      "reload": 300
    },
    "valueScrollbar": {
      "autoGridCount": true
    },
    "chartCursor": {
      "cursorColor": "#55bb76",
      "valueBalloonsEnabled": false,
      "cursorAlpha": 0,
      "valueLineAlpha": 0.5,
      "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
      "valueLineEnabled": true,
      "zoomable": false,
      "valueZoomable": true
    },
  });
});
```

I am attempting to recreate the same gantt chart - I have stripped back the bells and whistles in an effort to just display data but I'm having no joy.

[Link to CodePen with latest attempt](https://codepen.io/edwardinchains/pen/LKqbPM?editors=0010)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
--also any suggestions for renaming the question would be a bonus :P

Comment: Many of these properties don't exist in their docs for the `makeChart` method. https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#makeChart Where are you getting these from?

Comment: Sorry now I see these are gantt properties. Are they supposed to be added to the `.makeChart` mehtod?

Comment: Yes - this example works great, it's my attempt at converting to amCharts 4 that is the issue https://codepen.io/edwardinchains/pen/LKqbPM?editors=0010

Comment: Have you looked into the migration guide?https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/migrating-from-v3/ Important thing to understand is that V4 is not an upgrade to V3.

Comment: I have indeed "Since V4 is not an upgrade, but rather a whole new library, it does will not work off configurations made for V3." - I apologise for using the term upgrade in my question - I probably should have said migrate

Comment: Thanks it's clear to me now, sorry for the confusion. I'll take a stab at it, I don't have much experience with amCharts v4 but this might be a good oppourtunity.

Comment: Cheers - notice I added -  "also any suggestions for renaming the question would be a bonus :P" - I am still working on my question skills

Comment: Your data is empty if you console.log(chart.data); there is nothing there.

Comment: That's all I can look at for now, but it looks like some config options are missing. as per the example https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart/

Comment: I updated the codepen - when i console log (chart.dataSource) im getting object object, i think my issue lies in converting the timestamp into the date format the chart expects 'yyyy mm dd' - third can be altered though